# Create a circle using this class

Tags: geometry

i'm messing with a MMORPG game and i need to create a circle using this [class](https://pastebin.com/wQ1eM1dy)

The way i need to use it is the following:

```
ExServerPrimitive ex = new ExServerPrimitive("Circle", 
 object.getLocation());
 // Create the circle using the method addLine like  ex.addLine(Color.RED, x, y, z);
```

I tried see examples of how to create a circle using lines but i failed, mostly because i'm not good with math. Any help it will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit rusty on my math, but it should look something like this.

```
int centerX = 0;
int centerY = 0;
int radius = 10;
int segments = 10;

x1 = centerX - radius;
y1 = centerY;
int x2, y2;
int z1 = 0;
int z2 = 0;

for(int l = 1; l<=segments; l++)
{
  int angle = (360 / segments) * l;
  dx = cos(angle) * radius;
  dy = sin(angle) * radius;
  x2 = centerX + dx;
  y2 = centerY + dy; 
  ex.addLine(Color.RED, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2);
  x1 = x2;
  y1 = y2;
}
```

Comment: may i ask what are those values? The cos and the sin? I replaced the centerX with object.getLocation().getX() and the centerY with object.getLocation().getY() but what about the cos and sin?

Comment: sine and cosine, search the web how to use these functions in Java

Comment: Is the Math.sin() and Math.cos() if yes i did but i still dont get how to use the other variables you wrote example what is the centerX and centerY? i need replace those with something? The location i have to spawn the primitive is just one location variable which contain X-Y-Z data.  I would be really appreciate if you provide some info for the variables. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Center of the circle. Segments determine how many edges your circle will have, the more segments the smoother it will look. Surely I don't have to explain what radius means?

Comment: Basically for each segment of the circle we want to find the x and the y distance from the center of the circle to that point (dx, dy). Then we draw the line from the last point to this one.

Comment: The question i have is: 1. center is not existed variable. you mean i have to create it ? Or its the centerX, centerY?     2. y2 = x2 says The assignment to variable y2 has no effect

Comment: Sorry, x1 = center - radius; is supposed to be centerX - radius. Same for y

Comment: Sir first of all thank you and i love you for respond to me. Second i made it like that still in game when i spawn the promitive i see no circle. So something is wrong. https://pastebin.com/auM12C1w

Comment: 1. You forgot this y1 = y2;
2. You might need to convert degrees to radians: Cos((Math.PI / 180) * angle)
otherwise my function should give the right coordinates for a circle, anything else you need to figure out on your own